# How to get conversation contents in Softlayer tickets using SoftLayer API explorer

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to get the conversation contents between myself and the SL employee for a specific ticket using Softlayer API explorer.

So lets say that I made a ticket and the employee responded like `'Softlayer system administrator has completed the server upgrade. blah blah~'`.

What I want to do is display the `'Softlayer system administrator has completed the server upgrade. blah blah~'` text in the `'API output'` section in the SL API explorer.

[image]

To the best of my guess, I think first I need to set service to `'Ticket'` and set HTTP method to `'GET'`, and use one of the many API methods, but I'm having a hard time finding which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Rest Request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Ticket/27637317/getUpdates

Method: Get
```

Replace: $user, $apiKey and 27637317 with your own information.

To retrieve an account's associated tickets.

- [SoftLayer_Account::getTickets](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getTickets)

Comment: Is it possible to write Rest Request in SL API Explorer? I'm sorry but can you tell me specifically where can I type in that Rest Request in SL API Explorer? I can't seem to find it

Comment: You can use the explorer, paste the Rest Request in the address bar, also you can use a tool, for example I used: [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)